# Create a package of products as one Item in woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

How can we create a package of items as one product?

Example (Keyboard, mouse and Screen) as one product with one price for all of them and the user can't change the quantity of any of them.

I tried the group product but the user can change the quantity.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be for you to add a new product with the correct price including all 3 pieces, with images of all 3 products.

Then you could create a tab or a section further down on the product page that lists the products that the bundle includes. So when the user purchases the product they know which parts they would be getting for that price.

If the different components could also be sold seperately you could make a product loop further down the page with links to the product pages of the components.

Another option would be for you to try the woocommerce plugin https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/ which would let you create this functionality out of the box with a product type called "Bundled Product".

Hope this helps.